# Do changes in Accounts through the AccountManager invoke the Service to be recreated?

Tags: android, android-service, android-syncadapter

I have a Service with a corresponding SyncAdapter. Furthermore I manage account data through the AccountManager, on for example the following way:

```
    AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) mContext.getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
    Account account;
    if (accounts.length != 0) {
        account = new Account(Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        accountManager.setPassword(account, null);
    }
```

If I call this method from the SyncAdapter's onPerform, the Service gets into a loop of creation, binding and destroy. I check the logs (by setting the logcat filter to "No filter"), and I see logs from the SyncManager saying:
`SyncManager: account change detect - update database`. Right after this the service is destroyed, created and bound. The SyncAdapter's onPerform runs again, performing the same changes to the accounts, etc.: loop.

My question is: does a change in accounts cause the Service and corresponding SyncAdapter to be recreated?

Comment: this is happening to me.  did you find a solution?

Comment: I have abandoned this project since then, so I'm not 100% up-to-date anymore with the context anymore, but if I recall correctly a solution to this could be to do the check whether the account exists in the activity (or actual application class in my case), and not in the SyncAdapter. If the SyncAdapter detects a problem that it can't recover from, create a push notification that pulls the user to the app.

Comment: thanks fo your response.  i got it working by adjusting the program flow